# Extraction using istringstream?

Tags: c++

I have the following:

```
char op; double x, y, z;
istringstream iss("v 1.0 2.0 3.0", istringstream::in);
iss>>op>>x>>y>>z;
```

But on outputting the values of x,y and z they all return 0?

Update:

I guess it is working then but I am outputting it as :

```
int length=wsprintf(result," V is %d, %d, %d ", x, y, z);
TextOut(hdc,0,0,result,length);
```

and it doesn't show correct values.

But, it works fine if the values were in int for eg:

```
char op; int x, y, z;
istringstream iss("v 1 2 3", istringstream::in);
iss>>op>>x>>y>>z;
```

Comment: Code looks fine. [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) or it didn't happen :)

Comment: How are you outputting them?

Answer (score 1):

The `%d` format specifier expects an `int`, but `x`, `y` and `z` are of type `double`. If the type and format specifier do not match the behaviour is undefined. Note from the reference page for [`wsprintf`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms647550%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) there does not appear to be any format specifier for a `double`.

Suggest using a [`std::wostringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostringstream) and [`std::wstring`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) instead:

```
std::wostringstream ws;
ws << L" V is " << x << L"," << y << L"," << z;
const std::wstring result(ws.str());
TextOut(hdc,0,0,result.c_str(), result.length());
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks hmjd.

For anyone else, this is what I did to output the values correctly.

```
int length=sprintf_s(result," V is %0.1f, %0.1f, %0.1f ", x, y, z);
TextOut(hdc,0,0,result,length);
```

The general syntax "%A.B" means A digits before decimal point & B digits after decimal point.

Thanks all.